# Append HTML Using Shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I've written a Wordpress plugin that has a shortcode. The shortcode resides on a Wordpress page on which there are other shortcodes. The other shortcodes output HTML and I would like to append HTML from my shortcode to that output.

I was wondering if I could use a DOMDocument and getElementById to accomplish this.

The Wordpress page is like this:

[Shortcode #1]

[Shortcode #2]

[Shortcode #3]

[date_info]

My plugin does this:

```
function date_important_info(){

ob_start();
display_date($date);
$html = do_shortcode( ob_get_clean() );
return $html;

function display_date($date){ ?>
    <div style="">
        <span>Date:</span>
        <span><?php echo $date ?></span>
    </div>  
<?php }
}

add_shortcode('date_info','date_important_info');
```

My output appears at the bottom of the Wordpress page. I want the output from my shortcode to get appended to a div in the HTML that is output by one of the other shortcodes.

Comment: Where is this code? A plugin? Functions.php?

Comment: This code is in a plugin. The plugin has a shortcode. The shortcode is on a Wordpress page that includes a few other plugins.